# Dual booting Pop OS 21.04 and Windows 10

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, pop-os

So I had a working Windows 10 install on 1 SSD and I've installed Pop OS 21.04 on another separate SSD.

Since installing Pop I'm unable to boot back into windows.
The drive windows is installed on uses GPT partitioning.
The drive pop os is installed on is MBR

I've tried os-prober from pop-os and it doesn't see the windows installation.
I've tried using the windows install media to do startup repair and it doesn't find anything to do.

What other things can I try. I can reinstall windows if necessary, if it is necessary is there a guide to doing somewhere that takes account of the systemd booting I believe pop-os has switched to that means I will be able to dual boot? Including how to match the partition and install types?

I've found a number of guides and youtube videos about dual booting with pop os from which I gathered some of the info I've included above about partition types of each install is important.

I had some experience using grub to dual boot from a quite a few years ago and am not unfamiliar with the linux shell but I haven't been trying to dual boot for many years so am fairly rusty.

Comment: Did you change things in the BIOS menu to be able to install Pop OS? For example disbaling Secure Boot or enabling a "Compatibility Support Module" (CSM) or other "legacy" modes?

Comment: "The drive pop os is installed on is MBR" - **This was a huge mistake.**  This means you had to enable CSM, and since Windows was installed on GPT, that like;y means CSM was originally disabled.  Since you installed Windows with UEFI mode, it's incompatible, with CSM mode being enabled.

Comment: So interestingly I didn't change anything in the bios for the pop install, but csm may already have been on. Sounds like I should ensure csm is off and then reinstall pop? Will it likely detect windows at that point?

Comment: I was also surprised when I realised pop was using mbr as I had assumed a recent os would default to gpt

Answer (score 0):

1. Update Your System

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

2. Installing OS-Prober

Now we will install a tool to help Pop!_OS recognize the Windows partition.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install os-prober

sudo os-prober
```

You should see something similar to /dev/sda#:Windows 10:Windows;chain

Run this command so GRUB can update with the new partition data:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Dual Boot Complete!

Now when you restart your computer you will be greeted with the GRUB boot loader on start-up. You will be able to select the partition to boot into. By default it will be set to Pop!_OS so you will have a few seconds to select Windows before it automatically boots into Pop!_OS.